# how to get Delete and view button in the google docs spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

I have created a google doc form but it shows only submit button.How can i get view,Edit and Delete buttons in the form.How to view the data from the spreadsheet in the form page created?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you can't. You would need to go to Google Docs and look at the sheet. Besides, adding those buttons would require "Everyone" to have full permission to the sheet, meaning anyone could tamper with your data that ran across your spreadsheet.